# Имплементация Repository паттерна в Laravel

Tags: laravel, шаблоны-проектирования, php, repository

Всем привет!

С недавних пор изучаю `Laravel 4` и его возможности. Стала задача имплементировать паттерн Repository, чтобы вынести логику работы с бд туда. И вот тут столкнулся с рядом неудобств или непониманием, как правильно все организовать. Общий вопрос у меня звучит примерно так: **возможна ли реализация и применение этого паттерна в `Laravel` без лишней головной боли и стоит ли оно того**?

Вопрос хотел бы разбить на несколько частей, которые вызвали у меня смятения.

1) В `Laravel` есть возможность на стадии определения роута биндить модель в качестве параметра контроллера (например):

```
// routes.php
Route::bind('article', function($slug)
{
    return Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});

Route::get('articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@getArticle');

// controllers/ArticlesController.php
class ArticlesController extends BaseController {

    public function getArticle(Article $article)
    {
        return View::make('article.show', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

Если я хочу использовать паттерн `Repository`, то я не могу использовать такой подход, т.к. в этом случае контроллер явно будет знать о существовании модели `Article`? **Правильно ли будет переписать этот пример с использованием `Repository` таким образом**:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('articles/{slug}', 'ArticlesController@getArticle');

// controllers/ArticlesController.php
class ArticlesController extends BaseController {

    private $article;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $article) {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    public function getArticle($slug)
    {
        $article = $this->article->findBySlug($slug);

        return View::make('article.show', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

2) Допустим, мой вариант из предыдущего пункта с применением `Repository` оказался удачным. Теперь я хочу, чтобы при просмотре статьи у нее увеличивался счетчик просмотров, при этом я хочу вынести эту обработку в `Event`. То есть код будет следующим:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('articles/{slug}', 'ArticlesController@getArticle');

// controllers/ArticlesController.php
class ArticlesController extends BaseController {

    private $article;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $article) {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    public function getArticle($slug)
    {
        $article = $this->article->findBySlug($slug);
        Events::fire('article.shown');

        return View::make('articles.single', compact('article'));
    }
}

// некий subscriber, подписанный на события
class ArticleSubscriber {

    public function onShown()
    {
        // почему нету реализации, описано ниже
    }

    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen('article.shown', 'ArticleSubscriber@onShown');
    }

}
```

На данном этапе я снова был озадачен тем, как правильно реализовать обработку события. Передать модель статьи `$article` в событие я не могу, т.к. это опять нарушает принципы ООП и мой subscriber будет знать о существовании модели article. То есть сделать так я не могу:

```
// controllers/ArticlesController.php
...
\Events::fire('article.shown', $article);
...

// некий subscriber, подписанный на события
...
public function onShown(Article $article)
{
    $article->increment('views');
}
...
```

С другой стороны, внедрять в `subscriber` репозиторий `ArticleRepository` я тоже не вижу смысла, потому что мне снова придется сперва найти статью, а потом обновить ее счетчик, в итоге получится лишний запрос к бд:

```
// controllers/ArticlesController.php
...
Events::fire('article.shown', $slug);
...

// некий subscriber, подписанный на события
...
private $article;

public function __construct(ArticleRepository $articleRepository) 
{
    $this->article = $articleRepository;
}

public function onShown($slug)
{
    $article = $this->articleRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    $article->increment('views');
}
...
```

Более того, после того, как `Event` отработал (т.е. увеличил счетчик просмотров), необходимо, чтобы контроллер знал об обновленной модели, т.к. в представлении нужно вывести обновленный счетчик просмотров. Получается, что каким-то образом мне еще и необходимо вернуть новую модель из `Event`, но не хотелось бы, чтобы `Event` становился обычным методом для обработки какого-то действия (для этого ведь есть репозиторий) и возвращал какое-то значение. Вдобавок ко всему, вы можете заметить, что моя последняя реализация `onShow()` снова противоречит правилам паттерна `Repository`, но я не понимаю, как вынести эту логику в репозиторий:

```
public function onShown($slug)
{
    $article = $this->articleRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    // НЕВЕРНО! т.к. Event не должен знать о том, что умеет модель в реализации Eloquent
    // $article->increment('views');
}
```

**Можно ли найденную модель передать обратно в репозиторий и уже там увеличить ей счетчик (имеется ввиду, не противоречит ли такой подход паттерну?)?** Примерно так:

```
public function onShown($slug)
{
    $article = $this->articleRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    $this->articleRepository->updateViews($article);
}

// ArticleRepository.php
...
public function updateViews(Article $article) {
    $article->increment('views');
}
...
```

В качестве итога попробую сформулировать все компактнее:

1. При использовании паттерна
       `Repository` мне придется отказаться
       от передачи модели в контроллер и подобных удобностей?
2. Возможно ли при использовании
       репозитория держать в нем состояние
       модели и передавать его между
       сущностями (например, из фильтра в
       контроллер, из контроллера в `Event` и
       обратно) во избежание непотребных
       повторных обращений к бд, и
       правильный ли это будет подход
       (сохранение состояния модели)?

Такие дела, такие вот у меня вопросы. Хотелось бы услышать ответы, мысли, комментарии. Быть может, я не так пытаюсь применить паттерн? Сейчас он вызывает больше головной боли, нежели решает проблему дата маппинга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приветствую!

Раз Вам нужно инкрементировать счётчик всегда, когда открывается статья, то не лучше ли будет вызывать increment() непосредственно из метода репозитория findBySlug($slug) и делать вызов не от модели $article, а сделать это методом самого репозитория?

Что касается подхода с использованием событийной модели, то тут можно предложить использовать принцип Command-Query separation с использованием того же [Commander](https://github.com/laracasts/Commander) от Джеффри (и/или [Querier](https://github.com/smgladkovskiy/querier), что в данном случае больше подойдёт по концепции). При этом в контроллере у Вас будет вызов команды (тут и далее пишу так, если Вы будете пользовать Commander):

```
// controllers/ArticlesController.php
class ArticlesController extends BaseController {

    public function getArticle($slug)
    {
        $article = $this->execute(ArticleShowCommand::class, compact('slug'));

        return View::make('article.show', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

В команде у Вас будет получение из репозитория и вызов сопутствующих событий:

```
// Site/Commands/Article/ArticleShowCommandHandler.php
use Laracasts\Commander\CommandHandler;
use Laracasts\Commander\Events\DispatchableTrait;

class ArticleShowCommandHandler implements CommandHandler {

    use DispatchableTrait;

    private $article;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $articleRepository) 
    {
        $this->article = $articleRepository;
    }

    public function handle($command)
    {
        $article = $this->articleRepository->findBySlug($command->slug);

        $this->dispatchEventsFor($article);

        return $article ;
    }

}
```

А в репозитории, при выдаче данных, заводите нужное событие:

```
// Site/Repositories/ArticleRepository.php
public static function findBySlug($slug)
{
    $article = Article::where('article_alias', $slug);

    $article->raise(new ArticleWarViewed($article));

    return $job;
}
```

Ну и уже создание листнеров нужных и реализация там нужной логики по инкрементации просмотров и прочего - смотрите README.md в репозитории...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, данное решение мне вполне подходит. Хотел уточнить такой момент, правильна ли это, что мы передаем в Event конкретно модель? 

    $article->raise(new ArticleWarViewed($article));

Comment: В своё время я задался тем же вопросом по поводу использования функционала пакета Commander. Так как есть ещё пласт задач, которые не подходят под логику команд, а больше - запросов ("Query" в "Command-Query Separation principle"). Это как раз тема с выводом всяких списков (сложных, которые комбинируются с использованием разных объектов), отчётов, аналитических выборок. Лексически - это не команды. По логике работы же достаточно близки к командам (можно порезать на те же слои, разве что без валидации). Для этих задач был сделан пакет [Querier](https://github.com/smgladkovskiy/querier).

Comment: Заходите в [laravelRUS чат](https://gitter.im/LaravelRUS/chat). Там можно будет обсудить эти и другие вопросы, касающиеся как архитектуры веб приложений в целом, так и на laravel в частности... :)

Answer (score 0):

http://fideloper.com/hexagonal-architecture